# MPU9250 - Calibration Not Saved with RTIMULib EEPROM Issues

Tags: sensors, esp8266, arduino-micro, eeprom

I'm using the MPU9250 and the RTIMULib to perform sensor fusion, however, when I run ArduinoMagCal, and save the calibration, and follow that with running the main ArduinoIMU it claims the calibration file is not saved, and there is no data to use. I'm trying to determine why this is - I have tried the other MPU9250 libraries without luck, as this one is working on my setup (Arduino Micro -> eventually NodeMCU).

Repo : https://github.com/maxouille/RTIMULib-Arduino

ArduinoMagCal

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  This file is part of RTIMULib-Arduino
//
//  Copyright (c) 2014-2015, richards-tech
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of 
//  this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in 
//  the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, 
//  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the 
//  Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, 
//  subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all 
//  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, 
//  INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
//  PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT 
//  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION 
//  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE 
//  SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

#include <Wire.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "RTIMUSettings.h"
#include "RTIMU.h"
#include "CalLib.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>

RTIMU *imu;                                           // the IMU object
RTIMUSettings settings;                               // the settings object
CALLIB_DATA calData;                                  // the calibration data

//  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED defines the speed to use for the debug serial port

#define  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED  115200

void setup()
{
  calLibRead(0, &calData);                           // pick up existing mag data if there   

  calData.magValid = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    calData.magMin[i] = 10000000;                    // init mag cal data
    calData.magMax[i] = -10000000;
  }

  Serial.begin(SERIAL_PORT_SPEED);
  Serial.println("ArduinoMagCal starting");
  Serial.println("Enter s to save current data to EEPROM");
  Wire.begin();

  imu = RTIMU::createIMU(&settings);                 // create the imu object
  imu->IMUInit();
  imu->setCalibrationMode(true);                     // make sure we get raw data
  Serial.print("ArduinoIMU calibrating device "); Serial.println(imu->IMUName());
}

void loop()
{  
  boolean changed;
  RTVector3 mag;

  if (imu->IMURead()) {                                 // get the latest data
    changed = false;
    mag = imu->getCompass();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (mag.data(i) < calData.magMin[i]) {
        calData.magMin[i] = mag.data(i);
        changed = true;
      }
      if (mag.data(i) > calData.magMax[i]) {
        calData.magMax[i] = mag.data(i);
        changed = true;
      }
    }

    if (changed) {
      Serial.println("-------");
      Serial.print("minX: "); Serial.print(calData.magMin[0]);
      Serial.print(" maxX: "); Serial.print(calData.magMax[0]); Serial.println();
      Serial.print("minY: "); Serial.print(calData.magMin[1]);
      Serial.print(" maxY: "); Serial.print(calData.magMax[1]); Serial.println();
      Serial.print("minZ: "); Serial.print(calData.magMin[2]);
      Serial.print(" maxZ: "); Serial.print(calData.magMax[2]); Serial.println();
    }
  }

  if (Serial.available()) {
    if (Serial.read() == 's') {                  // save the data
      calData.magValid = true;
      calLibWrite(0, &calData);
      Serial.print("Mag cal data saved for device "); Serial.println(imu->IMUName());
    }
  }
}
```

ArduinoIMU

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  This file is part of RTIMULib-Arduino
//
//  Copyright (c) 2014-2015, richards-tech
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of 
//  this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in 
//  the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, 
//  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the 
//  Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, 
//  subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all 
//  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, 
//  INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
//  PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT 
//  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION 
//  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE 
//  SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

#include <Wire.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "RTIMUSettings.h"
#include "RTIMU.h"
#include "RTFusionRTQF.h" 
#include "CalLib.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>

RTIMU *imu;                                           // the IMU object
RTFusionRTQF fusion;                                  // the fusion object
RTIMUSettings settings;                               // the settings object

//  DISPLAY_INTERVAL sets the rate at which results are displayed

#define DISPLAY_INTERVAL  300                         // interval between pose displays

//  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED defines the speed to use for the debug serial port

#define  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED  115200

unsigned long lastDisplay;
unsigned long lastRate;
int sampleCount;

void setup()
{
    int errcode;

    Serial.begin(SERIAL_PORT_SPEED);
    Wire.begin();
    imu = RTIMU::createIMU(&settings);                        // create the imu object

    Serial.print("ArduinoIMU starting using device "); Serial.println(imu->IMUName());
    if ((errcode = imu->IMUInit()) < 0) {
        Serial.print("Failed to init IMU: "); Serial.println(errcode);
    }

    if (imu->getCalibrationValid())
        Serial.println("Using compass calibration");
    else
        Serial.println("No valid compass calibration data");

    lastDisplay = lastRate = millis();
    sampleCount = 0;

    // Slerp power controls the fusion and can be between 0 and 1
    // 0 means that only gyros are used, 1 means that only accels/compass are used
    // In-between gives the fusion mix.

    fusion.setSlerpPower(1);

    // use of sensors in the fusion algorithm can be controlled here
    // change any of these to false to disable that sensor

    fusion.setGyroEnable(false);
    fusion.setAccelEnable(true);
    fusion.setCompassEnable(true);
}

void loop()
{  
    unsigned long now = millis();
    unsigned long delta;
    int loopCount = 1;

    while (imu->IMURead()) {                                // get the latest data if ready yet
        // this flushes remaining data in case we are falling behind
        if (++loopCount >= 10)
            continue;
        fusion.newIMUData(imu->getGyro(), imu->getAccel(), imu->getCompass(), imu->getTimestamp());
        sampleCount++;
        if ((delta = now - lastRate) >= 1000) {
            Serial.print("Sample rate: "); Serial.print(sampleCount);
            if (imu->IMUGyroBiasValid())
                Serial.println(", gyro bias valid");
            else
                Serial.println(", calculating gyro bias");

            sampleCount = 0;
            lastRate = now;
        }
        if ((now - lastDisplay) >= DISPLAY_INTERVAL) {
            lastDisplay = now;
//          RTMath::display("Gyro:", (RTVector3&)imu->getGyro());                // gyro data
//          RTMath::display("Accel:", (RTVector3&)imu->getAccel());              // accel data
            //RTMath::display("Mag:", (RTVector3&)imu->getCompass());              // compass data
            RTMath::displayRollPitchYaw("Pose:", (RTVector3&)fusion.getFusionPose()); // fused output
           Serial.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly in the repo, you will see a CalLib folder with the CalLib.cpp program inside, wondering if it is saving to the EEPROM incorrectly?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  This file is part of RTIMULib-Arduino
//
//  Copyright (c) 2014-2015, richards-tech
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of 
//  this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in 
//  the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, 
//  copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the 
//  Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, 
//  subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all 
//  copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, 
//  INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
//  PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT 
//  HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION 
//  OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE 
//  SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

#include "CalLib.h"
#ifdef __SAM3X8E__

// Due version

#include "DueFlash.h"

DueFlash flash;

void calLibErase(byte device)
{
    uint32_t data = 0;

    flash.write(CALLIB_START + sizeof(CALLIB_DATA) * device, &data, 1); // just destroy the valid byte
}

void calLibWrite(byte device, CALLIB_DATA *calData)
{
    calData->validL = CALLIB_DATA_VALID_LOW;
    calData->validH = CALLIB_DATA_VALID_HIGH;

    flash.write(CALLIB_START + sizeof(CALLIB_DATA) * device, (uint32_t *)calData, sizeof(CALLIB_DATA) / 4);
}

boolean calLibRead(byte device, CALLIB_DATA *calData)
{
    memcpy(calData, CALLIB_START + sizeof(CALLIB_DATA) * device, sizeof(CALLIB_DATA));
    return calData->valid == CALLIB_DATA_VALID;
}

#else

// AVR version

#include <EEPROM.h>

void calLibErase(byte device)
{
    EEPROM.write(sizeof(CALLIB_DATA) * device, 0); // just destroy the valid byte
    //EEPROM.commit();
}

void calLibWrite(byte device, CALLIB_DATA *calData)
{
  byte *ptr = (byte *)calData;
  byte length = sizeof(CALLIB_DATA);
  int eeprom = sizeof(CALLIB_DATA) * device;

  calData->validL = CALLIB_DATA_VALID_LOW;
  calData->validH = CALLIB_DATA_VALID_HIGH;

  for (byte i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    EEPROM.write(eeprom + i, *ptr++);
    //EEPROM.commit();
  }
}

boolean calLibRead(byte device, CALLIB_DATA *calData)
{
  byte *ptr = (byte *)calData;
  byte length = sizeof(CALLIB_DATA);
  int eeprom = sizeof(CALLIB_DATA) * device;

  calData->magValid = false;

  if ((EEPROM.read(eeprom) != CALLIB_DATA_VALID_LOW) ||
      (EEPROM.read(eeprom + 1) != CALLIB_DATA_VALID_HIGH)) {
    return false;                                  // invalid data
  }

  for (byte i = 0; i < length; i++)
    *ptr++ = EEPROM.read(eeprom + i);
  return true;  
}
#endif
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're flashing your device, but anytime you flash an Arduino the EEPROM is cleared. This might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a compilation error which was preventing me from seeing that the data was indeed being saved to EEPROM, as far as I know there are no more issues. Just be mindful if you want to test it to add this in your calibration file after the save line:

```
  if (imu->getCalibrationValid())
      Serial.println("Using compass calibration");
  else
      Serial.println("No valid compass calibration data");
```